# Application.OnTime in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Application.OnTime when:=Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), Name:="Convert_NextGen_Doc_to_PDF_Realtime"
```

This was working fine when we had it running on a Windows Server 2008 with MS Word 2010 but as soon as we updated it to Windows Server 2012 R2 and MS Word 2016, it stopped working.  Once the 2 minutes has passed in the delay, the macro won’t run and the only way you can get it to work is connect to the server and then the macro seems to “wake up” and then it picks back up and runs fine.  I wanted to see if it was something with the server version or if the server was going into “sleep mode” so I installed the macro on my computer.  It would do the same thing to where once the 2 minute delay passed, the only way the macro would run would be when I made Word my active window and then the macro would resume running.

Comment: To rule out it being a problem with the macro you're calling, maybe try replacing `Convert_NextGen_Doc_to_PDF_Realtime` with a simple method like (eg) `Public Sub Tester(): Debug.Print "Ran", Now: End Sub` and see if that runs OK?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with calling of the macro because when i connect back to the server, it executes the "calling of the macro", it's just that it doesn't do it after the 2 minute delay.

Comment: Seems to be a known problem for Word 2016 and later: if Word has lost focus then OnTime doesn't fire.  You'd need a non-VBA way to run the macro like a vbscript running in a loop, or maybe Windows Task Scheduler